# Creating a menu like the "Notification Bar"

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-menu, android-notification-bar

I need to create a menu like the Notification bar, at the bottom of my application. Which means, you can drag the notification bar right? That is what I need as well.

For an example, before dragging, the menu should stay at the bottom like below

[image]

After the dragging, it should be like this

[image]

Up to now, all the Menus I have dealt with had something to with the Menu button, but this one doesn't. How can I create like this?

Comment: Being honest, I have no clue what you are talking about. The images also do not provide an insight. Do you want to create some kind of sidebar?

Comment: @AntonSack:
 
These kind of menus are all over the non smart phones. OK, lets say it is a side bar. In faceBook app, you can drag right to open a menu right? I need the same to be done, but the bar should come from the bottom. Apart from that, a small part of the bar, should be always visible at the bottom so user knows there is a menu

Answer (score 1):

use Sliding Drawer to achieve this

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html

SlidingDrawerActivity.java

```
public class SlidingDrawerActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
 Button slideButton, b1, b2, b3;
 SlidingDrawer slidingDrawer;

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_sliding_drawer);
  slideButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.slideButton);
  slidingDrawer = (SlidingDrawer) findViewById(R.id.SlidingDrawer);
  b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
  b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button02);
  b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button03);
  b1.setOnClickListener(this);
  b2.setOnClickListener(this);
  b3.setOnClickListener(this);
  slidingDrawer.setOnDrawerOpenListener(new OnDrawerOpenListener() {
   @Override
   public void onDrawerOpened() {
    slideButton.setText("V");
   }
  });
  slidingDrawer.setOnDrawerCloseListener(new OnDrawerCloseListener() {
   @Override
   public void onDrawerClosed() {
    slideButton.setText("^");
   }
  });
 }

 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
  Button b = (Button) v;
  Toast.makeText(SlidingDrawerActivity.this,
    b.getText() + " is Clicked :)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
}
```

activity_sliding_drawer.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Drag the control at the bottom"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        tools:context=".SlidingDrawerActivity" />

    <SlidingDrawer
        android:id="@+id/SlidingDrawer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="250dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:content="@+id/contentLayout"
        android:handle="@+id/slideButton"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dip" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/slideButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="^" >
        </Button>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/contentLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dip" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button01"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:text="Button 1" >
            </Button>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button02"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:text="Button 2" >
            </Button>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button03"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:text="Button 3" >
            </Button>
        </LinearLayout>
    </SlidingDrawer>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need this library in your project. Its [Android Sliding Up Panel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel) by Umano.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want, just do some change to positioning

[Sliding Layer](http://www.androidviews.net/2013/04/sliding-layer/)

Comment: Be carefull. Sliding Drawer is deprecated http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html you have to refer to 'Navigation Drawer' which is what Android advise.